# Issue with python version 2.7.3 importing maxrepeat module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

I am trying to import maxrepeat module in python 2.7.3 and couldn’t get much information in google can some one please help.

What is the module that helps maxrepeat module to work ?

I am able to import maxrepeat module using “from _sre import maxrepeat” but still fails while runnninv automation .

Comment: `MAXREPEAT` is not a module, it's a constant defined in `_sre`. Why do you need to access `_sre.MAXREPEAT`? This is an internal constant that you should not need to be concerned with.

Comment: I am not sure about why but my team want to use this and couldn’t get much help on this.

Comment: Can you please share how to import and use maxrepeat

Comment: You say that you can import it. How does it fail when you try to use it while "running automation"? What are you doing with it? Please add the error message to your question.

Comment: Yes you are right.checking on this this could not be an python issue . Thanks for your comments @mhawke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MAXREPEAT` is used *internally* by the `re` module as an upper limit for the minimum, maximum, or exact number of repetitions that can be specified in a pattern. For example:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.compile(r'a{100}')         # exactly 100 "a"s
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x7fa68be10780>
>>> re.compile(r'a{100, 200}')    # between 100 and 200 "a"s
```

Equalling or exceeding `MAXREPEAT` in a repetition value causes an exception to be raised by the regular expression parser in module `sre_parse`:

```
>>> from sre_constants import MAXREPEAT
>>> MAXREPEAT
4294967295L

>>> re.compile(r'a{{{}}}'.format(MAXREPEAT-1))
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x7f0ec959f660>

>>> re.compile(r'a{{{}}}'.format(MAXREPEAT))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py", line 194, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/re.py", line 249, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 572, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 716, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, 0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 324, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 518, in _parse
    raise OverflowError("the repetition number is too large")
OverflowError: the repetition number is too large
```

There should not be any reason to care about `MAXREPEAT` with normal use of the `re` module. If you need to handle errors then use the exception:

```
try:
    re.compile(r'a{{{}}}'.format(MAXREPEAT))
except OverflowError as exc:
    print 'Failed to compile pattern: {}'.format(exc.message)
```